# OCSP responder penetration testing

Tags: penetration-test, ocsp

I have to do penetration testing on an OCSP responder. Are there any frameworks for OCSP pentesting? since it does not include any web applications to test, should I only run network penetration tests on an OCSP responder? Is it possible to pentest an OCSP responder in a black box manner?